# fatal error: 'vector' file not found, with Xcode 10

Tags: xcode, macos, command-line

I seem to be having an issue with macOS SDK headers on the command line after upgrading to Xcode 10. I know Apple added `macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg` in `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages`, which I have installed - but unfortunately that doesn't seem to have helped. Are there any other changes in Xcode 10 I may have missed?

Here is the log:

```
20:54.19 In file included from /Users/<user>/Workspace/modules/brotli/enc/backward_references.cc:9:
20:54.19 /Users/<user>/Workspace/modules/brotli/enc/./backward_references.h:12:10: fatal error: 'vector' file not found
20:54.19 #include <vector>
20:54.19          ^~~~~~~~
20:54.23 1 error generated.
20:54.23 make[5]: *** [host_backward_references.o] Error 1
20:54.23 make[4]: *** [modules/brotli/host] Error 2
20:54.23 make[4]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered this after upgrading to Xcode 10 on a project that depends on libstdc++ (and for reasons not relevant to the present discussion, cannot be upgraded to libc++).

Since Xcode 10 removes support for libstdc++, I had to copy the relevant assets from an old installation of Xcode 9. (Thankfully I had an old machine handy to do so.)

I had to take the `libstdc++.6.0.9.tbd` binary (and recreate the symlinks `libstdc++.6.tbd` and `libstdc++.tbd` pointing to it) from:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/

into the same place on the new, Xcode 10 machine.

In addition, I had to copy over the C++ headers at:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/